# registration or login script not working accurately?

Tags: php, mysql

I have tried enough to solve this problem. I have coded a script to register and login in my program.
The script works fine if I insert a small password but if i insert a long password like 123456789 then it does not work.
please check my code and point out the mistake.

Here is my script

```
  <?php
  //Turn off all error reporting
  error_reporting(0);
  define("ENCRYPTION_KEY", "greatindian");
   /**
  Returns an encrypted & utf8-encoded
   */
 function encrypt($pure_string, $encryption_key) {
 $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
 $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
$encrypted_string = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, $encryption_key, utf8_encode($pure_string), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
return $encrypted_string;
}

/**
Returns decrypted original string
*/
function decrypt($encrypted_string, $encryption_key) {
$iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
$decrypted_string = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, $encryption_key, $encrypted_string, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
return $decrypted_string;
  }
/*http://localhost/sgame.php?action=register&&name=mrugesh&&email=mrugesh.shah00143@gmail.com&&password=123456789&&key=nation*/
/* require the authentication as the parameter registration start here*/


if(($_GET['action'])&&($_GET['name'])&&($_GET['email'])&&($_GET['password'])&&($_GET['key'])) {

$action=$_GET['action'];
$name=$_GET['name'];
$email=$_GET['email'];
$password=$_GET['password'];
//$pass= md5($password);
$encrypted_password = encrypt($password, ENCRYPTION_KEY);
$key= $_GET['key'];
if($key=='nation'){

if($action=='register'){    

 $con = mysql_connect('localhost','root','rose') or die('Cannot connect to the DB');
 mysql_select_db('project',$con);

 /* grab the posts from the db */

 $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `register` (name,email,password)
 VALUES ('".$name."','".$email."', '".$encrypted_password."')");
 if($query){
       echo "Data inserted";
/*Auto genrated registration mail  */

 require_once('class.phpmailer.php');
 require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

 $mail = new PHPMailer();
 $mail->IsSMTP();
 $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
 $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
 $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
 $mail->Port = 587;
 $mail->Username = "ramesh123@gmail.com";
 $mail->Password = "123456789";
 $mail->SetFrom( $email, 'project');
 $mail->Subject = "Welcome to project";
 //$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
 $body= file_get_contents('email2.html');                              
 $address =$email;
 //$name=$name;
$mail->MsgHTML($body);
$mail->AddAddress($address);
if($mail->Send()) {
echo "Message sent!";
} else {
 echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
 }



   }

   mysql_close($con);
  //
 //$posts = array($json);
 $posts = array(1);
header('Content-type: application/json');
json_encode(array('posts'=>$posts));

 }
  }else{
  echo "You are not authorized person";
  }
  }
  /*login*/

  if(($_GET['action'])&&($_GET['email'])&&($_GET['password'])){
  $login= $_GET['action'];
  $email = $_GET['email'];
  $password = $_GET['password'];
  //$pass = md5($password);
  $encrypted_password = encrypt($password, ENCRYPTION_KEY);echo"<br>";


  /* insert this link in broweser to check the script
  http://localhost/sgame.php?action=login&&   email=mrugesh.shah00143@gmail.com&&password=123456789*/       

  if($login=='login'){
   $connect = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','rose')or die("Couldn't connect to database!");
   mysqli_select_db($connect,'project') or die ("Couldn't find database");

    $query = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM register WHERE email ='$email' ");
   $numrows=mysqli_num_rows($query);
   if($numrows!==0)
   {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
   {

      $dbpassword = $row['password'];
      $dbemail =    $row['email'];
   }




        if($dbpassword==$encrypted_password&&$dbemail==$email){

            $Return['status'] = 'true';
            $Return['message'] = "you are successfully logged in";




        }else{
            $Return['status'] = 'false';
            $Return['message']= " Please enter valid email and password";

         }


        header('Content-type: application/json');
        echo  json_encode($Return);


                    }                     

                  }
                }       

                 /*login ends here*/    
                ?>
```

Comment: Check the structure of the mysql table for storing the password - what is the actual error you get

Comment: no error but cant login with long password. in my database lenght of string is 120 and i tried it by increasing it to 500 but doesn't work.

Comment: how long is your password have you checked the values actually do match

Comment: kerry browser doesn't show encrypted password

Comment: it shows this �\��?���2���g
���?���2���g

Comment: Not the answer, But you should use  MySQLi or PDO instead of mysql. The mysql extension is not secured and deprecated and will be removed in the future:

Comment: And this current code definitely works with all shorter passwords?

Comment: but why it is not working for long password

Comment: i am asking if it definitely works with current code on all shorter passwords

Comment: yes it is working for small password..

Answer (score 0):

I could not get your code to encrypt and match login password entered and saved encrypted password.  Amended code and this seems to work fine.  I just concentrated on password matching so simulated database access and login by just setting 2 strings (that's what you pull from database anyway) also simplified things by not comparing email at this stage.  Get the password working first then you can begin adding other variables such as email etc.

```
<?php
define("ENCRYPTION_KEY", "greatindian");
function encrypt($pure_string, $encryption_key) {
 $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
 $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
$encrypted_string = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, $encryption_key, utf8_encode($pure_string), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
return $encrypted_string;
}
$registered_password = '12345678901234567890';
$encrypted_password = encrypt($registered_password, ENCRYPTION_KEY);
echo $encrypted_password.'<br>';
//store in database
//compare with login
$login_password='12345678901234567890';

if(encrypt($login_password, ENCRYPTION_KEY)==$encrypted_password){
    echo 'match';
}
else {echo 'no match';
}
?>
```

Comment: I suggest testing with above code, then introducing database, then email comparison.  It is quite a lot to test without more of the system and database.  If you still have problems perhaps a cutdown DB with sql dump to help me test